# Linq one-to-many Union

Tags: c#, linq

I'm developing a MVC web application using asp.net C# and VS2012 Express.

I have a table (`Organizations`) with one-to-many relationships with two other tables (`Comments` and `Proposals`). All three tables contain an `OrganizationID` field to maintain the relationships. All three tables have an `AddedBy` string field.

I want to find all Organizations where either the `Organization.AddedBy="Joe"` or `Comments.AddedBy="Joe"` or `Proposals.AddedBy="Joe"`.

These queries do a join, but I'm looking for a union that contains only the `Organizations' fields`.

```
// Find organizations created by this person.
IQueryable<Organization> org = from m in context.Organizations
where m.AddedBy.Equals("Joe")
select m;

// Find Comments created by this person.
IQueryable<Comment> comment = from m in context.Comments
where m.AddedBy.Equals("Joe")
select m;

// Join our two queries.
IQueryable<Comment> organizations = (from item in org
join c in comment on item.OrganizationID equals c.OrganizationID
select item).Distinct();

// Find Proposals created by this person.
IQueryable<Proposal> proposal = from m in context.Proposals
where m.AddedBy.Equals("Joe")
select m;

// Join our two queries.
organizations = (from item in organizations
join c in proposal on item.OrganizationID equals c.OrganizationID
select item).Distinct();
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is the problem? which part is not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Entity Framework you can do either:

```
var orgs =  context.Organizations
                   .Where(O => O.AddedBy.Equals("Joe") || 
                               O.Comments.Any(C => C.AddedBy.Equals("joe")) ||
                               O.Proposals.Any(P => P.AddedBy.Equals("joe")));
```

As **EF** maintaining the parent-child relationship with navigation properties.

Hope this will help !!

Comment: Brilliant. Concise. Merci Kundan!

Answer (score 0):

So you're looking for three different sets, all combined.  Just query each of those three things and then combine them using `Union`:

```
string user = "Joe";

var addedOrganizations = context.Organizations.Where(org => org.AddedBy == user);

var orgsWithUsersComments = from org in context.Organizations
    join c in context.Comments
    on org.OrganizationID equals c.OrganizationID
    where c.AddedBy == user
    select org;

var orgsWithUsersProposals = from org in context.Organizations
    join p in context.Proposals
    where p.AddedBy == user
    select org;

var combinedResults = addedOrganizations.Union(orgsWithUsersComments)
    .Union(orgsWithUsersProposals);
```